# Homeomorphism in a normed space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Let $X$ a normed space. Prove that

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{1+\Vert x \Vert} $$

is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $U=B(0,1) = \{ x\in X / \Vert x \Vert < 1 \}$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ Consider $g(x)=\dfrac{x}{1-\Vert x \Vert}$, then $f \circ g =$id$|_{U}$ and $g \circ f =$id$|_{X}$ so $g=f^{-1}$.

Consider $\alpha: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha(x)=1+\Vert x \Vert$. How $\alpha(x) \neq 0$ then $\dfrac{1}{\alpha}$ is continuous.

Also, $h_1 : X \rightarrow X$, $h_1(x)=x$ is continuous. So $f=\alpha h_1 : X \rightarrow U$ is continuous.

Analogously consider $\beta: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\beta(x)=1- \Vert x\Vert$. How $\beta(x) \neq 0$ then $\dfrac{1}{\beta}$ is continuous.

Also, $h_2 : U \rightarrow X$, $h_2(x)=x$ is continuous. So $g=\beta h_2: U \rightarrow X$ is continuous.

It's correct?

Comment: Which $U$ are you refering to?

Comment: Sorry, $U=B(0,1)$.

Comment: Yes, your proof is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: "How $\alpha(x) \neq 0$ then $\dfrac{1}{\alpha}$ is continuous" is confusing. I recommend to write "Because $\alpha(x) \neq 0$, $\dfrac{1}{\alpha}$ is continuous."

Answer (score 1):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Yes, your proof is correct. However, you should explicity verify that $f$ and $g$ are inverse to each other (which is admittedly fairly trivial).

Answer (score 0):

I would prove that $f$ is bounded and injective so it is continous. Note that $f(X) =B(0,1)$, so it it enough to prove that $f^{-1}$ is bounded

Comment: What is your definition of a bounded fubction? What is the relation between "bounded" and "continuous"?

Comment: $f$ is bounded iff there exist $c \geq 0$ so that for all $x\in X$, $||f(x)|| \leq c||x||$

Comment: Then $f^{-1}$ is not bounded. I think the concept of a bounded function as you define it is most useful for *linear* functions. In that case boundedness and continuity are equivalent. In general your condition only assures continuity in $0$.